# Why different version of NPM is being used?

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10

It is my understanding that npm gets installed alongside node when I use the node installer in Windows 10, and will be located in "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" (I installed the 32 bit version to my D drive, C is my primary OS drive).

However, "npm's globally installed packages (including, potentially, npm itself) are stored separately in a user-specific directory (which is currently C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm)." - https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm

Initially, after I first installed nodejs, my Roaming/npm folder was empty since I did not install any packages globally. Afterwards, I wanted to upgrade my npm so I ran the following command - "npm i -g npm". This added the following items to my Roaming/npm folder.
[Roaming/npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNhaM.png)

Now, when I run npm -v, the updated version is shown (7.24.2).
My questions are:

1.) Since I only updated the global ( -g ) installed one ( %appdata%\npm\ ), the npm in "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" should remain as the old version right? (6.4.13).

2.) If so, why is the newer version being used, if (refer to below)

According to https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm, "it will always use the version of npm installed with node instead of the version of npm you installed using npm -g install npm@." This does not seem like the case for me.

I did a "echo %PATH%" in cmd and I have confirmed that "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" is indeed placed before "C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm". So why is the newer version being used instead?

I tried to open cmd in "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" and ran ".\npm.cmd -v" and it still gave me the same result which I was not expecting (7.24.2). I looked at the date modified for the nodejs folder and it does not seem like any changes were made.

Another thing I tried was logging in as a different user on my PC and running "npm -v", when I did that, it was showing the old version (which is what I expected since npm was only updated for my admin account, (admin\Appdata\Roaming\npm). So why is it that when I'm logged in as admin, it seems like the npm in "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" is updated as well?

Any help to enhance/correct my understanding would be greatly appreciated, I am still quite new to npm and node.

Update: I am aware that nvm exists. This question is asking about the behaviour mentioned above.

Comment: updating just npm instead of updating node, with the associated npm update, makes very little sense. And to make your life easier, use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) if you're on windows), so that you can properly manage the need for multiple different versions of node being all install concurrently.